# Syntax for class within a class in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

If I have the following

```
class A
    {
    public:
        int stuff;
            void helper(B temp, int d); //what about here? I'm getting a 'B' has not been declared error here.
    private:
        class B 
        {
        public:
            int stuffer;
        private:
            int x;
        };
    }:
```

Whats the correct way to refer to class 2 in my implementation file? Would it be
`1::2::someMethod`? Or `2::someMethod`?

Comment: `1` and `2` are not valid class names.

Comment: Ya I tried but I have way too many other errors so I'm not sure what traces back to what yet, but I just wanted to know the "official" ruling on this..

Comment: Note: Class B is private and can not be accessed from outside the class. Thus exposing a method 'helper' that uses a B is not going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, class name cannot start with integer. So renaming them:

```
 class A
 {
    public:
        int stuff;
    private:
        class B 
        {
        public:
            int stuffer;
        private:
            int x;
        };
  };
```

Second, since the nested class `B` is in the private section, so you cannot access it from outside the scope of class `A`. `B`  is accessible to `A` only. And the syntax of declaring an object of type `B` would be `B bObj;` in the scope of `A`.

Now you should try yourself first, before asking futher questions!

---

As for your edit (the added question): it's not compiling **because** by the time the compiler sees `B temp`, it has not yet seen the definition of `B`, that is why it says `B` is not declared!

The fix is very simple. Declare `B` before it's used, something like this:

```
class A
{
private:
        class B 
        {
        public:
            int stuffer;
        private:
            int x;
        };
    public:
        int stuff;
        void helper(B temp, int d);

 }; //<--- this is also fixed. your code has 'colon', instead semi-colon!
```

Also read the comment at the end of the class!

Comment: Whats oustide mean? Can I access it in my A.cpp file?

Comment: @bitmoe: Try, Experiment and Know!

Comment: @bitmoe: See my answer again!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 1 and 2 refer to REAL class names, `1::2::methodName` just like any other nested scoping.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a method of class 1, you can use 2::somemethod. In other places, use 1::2::somemethod. "Inside" includes method argument declarations in method implementations of class 1, but not return value declarations for method implementations of class 1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which scope level you're at.  Inside a member function for class 1, it would be `class_2::someMethod`.  At file scope, it would be `class_1::class_2::someMethod`.  It's always correct to fully qualify a function or variable name like that, but sometimes it's more typing than is strictly necessary.  In general, you need the scope resolution operator `::` when the compiler can't figure out on its own what you're referring to.

In practice, the best way to find out is **try it and see what happens**.  If the compiler gives you an error, throw the class name in front of it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for nested class:

```
Class class_name1
{  
    Private:
        Data members
    Public: 
        Member functions
        {
        .........
        }
        Class class_name2  //class2 is embedded with class1
        {
            Private:
                Data members
            Public: 
                Member functions
                {
                .........
                }
        };  // class2
};  //class1
```

Nested class is possible to define one class within another class since a class declaration does,define a scope.

A nested class is valid only within the scope of the enclosing class.

Need of nested class is virtually not existed.